# How to read the scanner back from the beginning with close() or reset()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have an 3x3 matrix input stream of where I am calculating the absolute difference of the sums across the two main diagonals. Example below:

> 11 2 4
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 10 8 -12

Should give me a result of 15 because:

| 11 + 5 - 12 | - | 4 + 5 + 10 |

= | 4 | - | 19 |

= 15

My code is below:

```
public class Solution {

static int diagSumL(int lines, Scanner in) {
    int currSum;
    currSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            in.nextInt();
        }
        currSum += in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(currSum);
        if (in.hasNextLine() == true) {
            in.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return currSum;
}

static int diagSumR(int lines, Scanner in) {
    int currSum, index;
    currSum = 0;
    for (int i = lines; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j--) {
            in.nextInt();
        }
        currSum += in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(currSum);
        if (in.hasNextLine() == true) {
            in.nextLine();
        };
    }
    return currSum;
}

static int absDiff(int a, int b) {
    return Math.abs(a) + Math.abs(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lines, sumDiagL, sumDiagR;
    lines = in.nextInt();
    sumDiagL = diagSumL(lines, in);
    in.close();
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    sumDiagR = diagSumR(lines, in);
    int result = absDiff(sumDiagL, sumDiagR);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

My code errors at the 3rd to last line which roots from my diagSumR method trying to call in.intNext() where the error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

What I want to do is reset the scanner so I can start fresh and re-read the scanner from the start(so I can calculate the sum of the other diagonal). Am I using close() wrong?(Every example of using close() online does it like this)

Also is it possible to use reset() from the Scanner class as an alternative, if so how?

Comment: You shouldn't need to reread anything. Store the matrix while reading, then process both diagonals.

Comment: I want to do it without having to store the matrix for memory purposes and wanted to try and implement it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Why it doesn't work.

This doesn't work because when you close the scanner with `close()` it doesn't only "close" the object but also the underlying `System.in`. So even when you create a new `Scanner` instance the underlying `System.in` will be closed hence the exception you're getting. This can be checked using `System.in.available();` before and after you call `close()`. Also it's not possible to reopen the stream after it's been closed.

Please follow the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--).

> if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked

`System.in` on the other hand returns a [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) which implements `Closeable, AutoCloseable`.

### 2. How it should be done.

Even if you don't want to store your matrix in memory your solution would be suboptimal as it would require the user to input the matrix twice since once something has been read from `System.in` you cannot re-read it with a `Scanner`! You have all the data there so you can actually compute both sums in one go storing 2 sum variables since you're reading in all the numbers anyway. Just pay attention which number is being added to which sum variable.

### 3. How it can be done.

Since you're passing that `Scanner` instance around anyway I don't see any reason to `close()` it and re-initializing before calling `diagSumR`, just close it at the end of the method. The drawback, as I mentioned is that you need to input the matrix again by hand.

Comment: great response, was also implementing it to do it in one go as stated in point 2, just need to figure it out on my mind almost had it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, whether the questions was to understand Scanner (You were trying to move backwards, that too after)

if not, this can be solved much simpler (assuming square matrices)

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    diagonal1 += A[i][i]; // 0,0 + 1,1 + 2,2 + ... + n,n
    diagonal2 += A[N-1-i][i]; // n,0 + n-1, 1, .. + 2,2 + 1, n-1 + 0,n
}
```

where N is the size of the matrix A (& I hope it is clear that the usage of N-1 was for index being from 0 to N-1)